# How to convert Int to Time(MM:SS.mm) swift

Tags: ios, swift, time, format

I have an Int, say `15344` and I'm sending it to a label as a string, but I want it to be formatted as `01:53.44`

```
var split = data.valueForKeyPath("time") as! Int
cell.textLabel?.text = split.description
```

but this only gives me the `15344` without format. I tried `.stringbyAppendingformat` but couldn't get it right. thanks in advance!

Comment: What does 15344 stand for? 15344 seconds, or 1 hour/53 minutes/44 seconds?

Comment: 15344 is 1min/53seconds/44ms

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is a strange way to store a time and perhaps you should think
about using the number of milliseconds instead. If that is not an option,
you can "dissect" the integer with

```
let time = 15344
let minutes = time / 10000
let seconds = (time / 100) % 100
let centis = time % 100
```

and then create a string with

```
let text = String(format:"%d:%02d.%02d", minutes, seconds, centis)
print(text) // 1:53.44
```

Comment: thank you!! the format string at the bottom was what I was missing. you're the best! also, I know it's a weird concept but it is the best way to execute what I'm doing

Comment: @EmmettScully: Glad to help. But reading your above comment again, I wonder: How can you store milliseconds in two digits? What would 1m / 23s / 456ms be ? Or is it "centiseconds" ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple solution would be

First convert it to string then,

```
let time = "15344"
let rangeOfSecond = Range(start: (advance(time.endIndex, -2)),
   end: time.endIndex)
let secondString = time.substringWithRange(rangeOfSecond)
```

For minute

```
let rangeOfMinute = Range(start: (advance(time.endIndex, -4)),
   end: time.endIndex - 2)
let minuteString = time.substringWithRange(rangeOfMinute)
```

Similarly for hour. Then concat all substrings with ":".

Answer (score -1):

This seems like a weird way to be doing time formatting. There is an NSDate api that uses NSDateFormatter for this purpose. The documentation can be found here:

```
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateFormatter_Class/
```

You might want to use:

```
func stringFromDate(_ date: NSDate) -> String
```

Comment: There is no NSDate. Just an int.